# Passing Array from Model to Controller to View in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter-2

I have a model that sends an error response to the controller in CodeIgniter that then is passed to the view which is just a JSON encoder. Here is the array from the model.

```
return $posts[] = array('complete'=>0,'error'=>1003, 'message'=>'Username already exists');
```

The issue I am having is that I need those square brackets after the $posts variable because sometimes I need an array of errors. However when I pass the single array to the view it encodes the JSON without the square brackets but when I have multiple arrays it includes the square brackets, I need the square brackets in the JSON every time. Here is the Controller...

```
$data['data'] = $this->logins_model->signup($post_data);  
$this->load->view('json', $data);
```

**Here is the view...**

```
header('Content-type: application/json');  
$response['response'] = $data;  
echo json_encode($response);
```

**I need the JSON response to look like this**

```
{
    "response": [
        {
            "complete": 0, 
            "error": 1003, 
            "message": "Username already exists"
        }
    ]
}
```

**NOT THIS!**

```
{
    "response": {
        "complete": 0, 
        "error": 1003, 
        "message": "Username already exists"
    }
}
```

Comment: json formatted string does not match the array that is returned by your model (and `json_encode`d later). Post relevant code, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to get array in `json` you should be having it in php array as well (i.e. data-structures should meet). So `$response['response'] = $data;` should be `$response['response'] = array($data);`

In your example `var_dump($response);` gives:

```
array(1) {
  ["response"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["complete"]=>
    int(0)
    ["error"]=>
    int(1003)
    ["message"]=>
    string(23) "Username already exists"
  }
}
```

As you see `$response['response']` is an object for `json`.

When you replace `$response['response'] = $data;` with `$response['response'] = array($data);` your data-structure, which you want to convert in json will become:

```
array(1) {
  ["response"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["complete"]=>
      int(0)
      ["error"]=>
      int(1003)
      ["message"]=>
      string(23) "Username already exists"
    }
  }
}
```

That will give you desired output because `json_encode` will expect that there might be another items in `$response['response']`.

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/S82Kbh)

**Edit**
Your model should be returning one dimensional array. For example:

```
return array('complete'=>0,'error'=>1003, 'message'=>'Username already exists');
```

And you should assign it to another array that is holding all error messages:

```
$data['data'][] = $this->logins_model->signup($post_data);
$this->load->view('json', $data);
```

[Demo 2](http://codepad.viper-7.com/lsOD4d)

Comment: That works for if there is one error message but if there is an multiple error messages then there are double square brackets.

Comment: the issue is the array of error arrays is built in the logins_model and returned there, it can't be combined with other error arrays with the $data variable. For example `for($i = 0; $i<10; $i++)
{
$posts[] = array('complete'=>0,'error'=>1003, 'message'=>'Username already exists');
}
return $posts;`

Comment: @StuartTheY If error array is constructed like this, you should get correct output. Let me post another demo. http://codepad.viper-7.com/qzK2GM

Comment: yes but now if you put array() around the $data variable on line 14 of your last demo there will be an extra set of brackets, see what I mean? It needs to be able to support a single array and arrays of arrays with just a single set of square brackets around it.

Comment: @StuartTheY http://codepad.viper-7.com/fingR9 I don't see what's the problem here.

Comment: Oh well I guess it works for a single array if I break it up into two lines for some reason like this. `   $posts[] = array('complete'=>0, 'error'=>1003, 'message'=>'Username already exists');
   return $posts;`

Comment: @StuartTheY Sure, it works. Actually does not matter technically where you create multi-dimensional array but I think it's better to be in controller. Glad that you solved you problem, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In your view define $post as an array and remove tha square brackets from there. To check your results in view use print_r instead of echo. Which will show exactly how many data is retrieved.

Comment: I need the square brackets in the model because sometimes I will build an array of arrays adding them on to the posts array and I leave out the [] then the array with only have the last item added to it.